# Need explanation on how JVM evaluates Operator precedence in java

Tags: java

currently I am preparing for OCAJP exam, I got a similar question following like this, the explanation which is given is not satisfactory.
  problem:

// some code

```
int a=2;
int c=6;
int v=a+c*(a=3);
System.out.println(v);
```

Why v is printed as 20, not 21?
as I know (*) operator will evaluates first.but here it is evaluates from left to right rule. also (a=3) is in parenthesis,so anyhow it should evaluates first.

Comment: Through operator precedence, `c` and `(a=3)` are determined to be operands of `*`. The result of that and `a` are determined to be the operands of `+`. Then evaluation begins from the left. `a` is evaluated and produces `2`. Then `c*(a=3)` is evaluated. `c` produces `6` and `(a=3)` sets `a` to `3` and produces `3`. `6*3` produces `18` and `2+18` produces `20`.

Comment: A relevant comment from the dupe link is *The idea that the entire thing in parentheses is evaluated first is simply false, so stop believing that.*

Comment: thank you so much guys , now I got it.